# Subprocess y gunicorn! Subprocess funciona no funciona cunado la aplicación está en producción con gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

¿Qué tal comunidad? Tengo un problema con subprocess cuando quiero poner mi aplicacion desarrollada en django en producción, el tema es que subprocess funciona bien cuando me encuentro en desarrollo pero cuando quiero poner mi aplicación en producción utilizando gunicorn y nginx, subprocess no funciona, no se si es un problema de permisos para gunicorn o de configuración.

Este es la configuración para el servicio de gunicorn que he creado gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=german
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/german/Documentos/myapp
ExecStart=/home/german/Documentos/myapp/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myapp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

gunicorn.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Y por último la configuración de nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/german/Documentos/myapp/static/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Para el servicio de gunicorn tambien probe cambiando el usuario a ROOT pero nada, y si tuviera que setear los permisos para este, como debería hacerlo? si alguien tiene alguna idea o se ha topado en este problema y pueda darme una mano desde ya gracias, saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no funciona"? (por no preguntar ya qué significa "funciona no funciona")

Comment: Hola que tal? No ejecuta los comando que le paso

Comment: Y no puedes ver mensajes de error en algún log? Yo sospecho que es un problema más bien de la ruta hacia el comando que intentas ejecutar con subprocess. Usa rutas absolutas para evitar problemas con el PATH

Comment: Esta es una linea de código de mi aplicación, `subprocess.run(["sh", str(BASE_DIR) + "/sh/get_icons.sh"])`, BASE_DIR me da la ruta absoluta de mi aplicación. Si me bancas, mañana te subo el error que me arroja, no tengo el aparato con migo en este momento, la aplicación va a correr en una raspberry y es para lo único que se va a usar la rasp..., desde ya, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Que tal? Disculpas por la demora, encontré este post [enlace](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/123) que parece ser el problema que tengo, hay que usar gevent parece si no entendí mal, voy a tener que leer mas al respecto, desde ya muchas gracias @abulafia.